# Why the figure showed by matplotlib has more than three colors while I have only three labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm starting to learn to use `matplotlib` to draw figures.
When I was using the famous [`iris`](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris) dataset and trying to draw a plot figure, I encountered a question.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

raw = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
data = raw.values
print data
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
pl.scatter(x,y,color = ['r','g','b'], s = [30,40,50], alpha=0.5)
pl.figure()
pl.show()
labels = set(data[:,4])
print labels
```

I got the output

```
 ...
 [6.7 3.3 5.7 2.5 'Iris-virginica']
 [6.7 3.0 5.2 2.3 'Iris-virginica']
 [6.3 2.5 5.0 1.9 'Iris-virginica']
 [6.5 3.0 5.2 2.0 'Iris-virginica']
 [6.2 3.4 5.4 2.3 'Iris-virginica']
 [5.9 3.0 5.1 1.8 'Iris-virginica']]
set(['Iris-virginica', 'Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor'])
```

I only used the first two features because I didn't know whether it is possible to draw high dimensional figures.

This is the figure I got
[image]

There were **more than three** colors while, you can see from the output, there were exactly **three** labels`('Iris-virginica', 'Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor')`.

I wonder how does matplotlib decide what color to use?
What are the different colors for?

What should I do to show a three-color plot figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obtained this figure with [pyplot.scatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=scatter#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter), more specifically with this line of code:

```
pl.scatter(x, y, color=['r','g','b'], s=[30,40,50], alpha=0.5)
```

In the line above, there is no indications whatsoever about labels. `x` and `y`  are only two list of numbers.

To color the dots, `scatter` uses the argument `color=['r', 'g', 'b']`. If `color` is the same size than `x` and `y`, then each dot has a defined color. But if `color` is smaller than `x` and `y`, then`scatter` will loop through `color` as many times as needed. For example:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    
color = ['r', 'g', 'b'] becomes ['r', 'g', 'b', 'r', 'g']
```

And for the last mystery *"why is there more than three colors on the plots"*, it's because the transparency `alpha` is set to 0.5 (all colors are 50% transparent). Some of the data points have the same `x` and `y` coordinates, so the colors overlay, and it looks like there's more colors than red, green, blue.

---

To plot the right colors, you need to use the labels informations. [Python scatter plot with colors corresponding to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318906/python-scatter-plot-with-colors-corresponding-to-strings) should help you.